# NW.JS Uncaught error: no module_name

Tags: node.js, nw.js

I package my app with nw.js v0.12.3 and I'm use dns node.js module. When I started my app with 'nw .' all works fine. But when I package my app with nw-packager I have an error 'Uncaught error: No module dns'.

Comment: We need more info. What have you tried? Is "dns" a module you installed via npm? It's possible your process is being started from a different working directory in the packaged app so your `require` calls are looking in the wrong place for modules.

Comment: @Chev, dns it's standart io.js module.
I added him like this `var dns = require('dns');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `dns` module via `npm install dns --save` (not `--save-dev`) so it's marked as a post-development dependency (`"dependencies":` in your `package.json` file instead of `"devDependencies":`) and is packaged with your app.

Then you should be able to check that the `dns` module is packed with your code and the nwjs runtime using a tool such as `7-Zip`.

`nw-packager` uses `nw-builder` under the hood so any manifest options (`package.json`) that are documented in `nw-builder` apply to `nw-packager`